# How do you define multiple query or mutation in GraphQLSchema

Tags: graphql

I am new to GraphQL. Forgive me if this is obvious.

Beside using `buildSchema`, is there a way to define more than one query/mutation using `new GraphQLSchema`?

This is what I have right now.

```
const schema = new graphql.GraphQLSchema(
    {
        query: new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
            name: 'RootQueryType',
            fields: {
                count: {
                    type: graphql.GraphQLInt,
                    resolve: function () {
                        return count;
                    }
                }
            }
        }),
        mutation: new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
            name: 'RootMutationType',
            fields: {
                updateCount: {
                    type: graphql.GraphQLInt,
                    description: 'Updates the count',
                    resolve: function () {
                        count += 1;
                        return count;
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Multiple "queries" are actually just multiple fields on one Query type. So just add more fields to that `GraphQLObjectType`, like so:

```
query: new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        count: {
            type: graphql.GraphQLInt,
            resolve: function () {
                return count;
            }
        },
        myNewField: {
            type: graphql.String,
            resolve: function () {
                return 'Hello world!';
            }
        }
    }
}),
```

Comment: Thank heaven for SO!